# How to list all possible combinations in a string with multiple given replacements?

Tags: python, string, jupyter-notebook, permutation

I'm stuck on a problem which I need to list the combinations of all possible replacements in a string. For instance, if the string is:

"ABCDXY1234ZEFGH"

And the possible replacements are (XY and Z is unchanged):

character 0 to 3 replaced with "IJKL"
character 6 to 9 replaced with "5678"
character 11 to 14 replaced with "MNOP"

Then the output would be seven strings:

ABCDXY1234ZMNOP,
ABCDXY5678ZEFGH,
ABCDXY5678ZMNOP,
IJKLXY1234ZEFGH,
IJKLXY1234ZMNOP,
IJKLXY5678ZEFGH,
IJKLXY5678ZMNOP.

How would you make this combination? I tried itertools but haven't figured it out yet.

Thank you, geniuses on the internet.